# Can someone help? need to find the a and b for this function. Anything helps!!

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, exponential-function, advice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99MRW.jpg)
Function is  $f(x)= ax^4-25x^3+2x^2+25x+b $
it passes through (7,E) E= 1296 and there is a zero of -1

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. When you [edit] the question to ask it directly rather than with a hard to read image, be sure to tell us what you tried and where you are stuck. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @EnriqueRodriguez Please add the function and your work into your question. If you show your effort appropriately, it is more likely that somebody will also put his/her effort into providing you some help.

Comment: @Ertxiem is this better?

Comment: @Brian i added the function is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find $a$ and $b$ as a system of equations:

We know that for $x=7$, $f(x)=1296$, this will be one equation on $a$ and $b$.

And for $x=-1$, $f(x) = 0$, this will give another equation on $a$ and $b$.

Can you write down the equations and solve the system or do you need more help?

**Edit:** The equations will be:
$$\begin{cases}
a \times 7^4 - 25 \times 7^3 + 2 \times 7^2+25 \times 7 + b = 1296 \\
a \times (-1)^4 - 25 \times (-1)^3 + 2 \times (-1)^2+25 \times (-1) + b = 0
\end{cases}$$

**Edit 2:** If you subtract the first equation from the second you get an equation without $b$:
$$a \times (7^4-(-1)^4) - 25 \times (7^3-(-1)^3) + 2 \times (7^2-(-1)^2) + 25 \times (7-(-1)) = 1296 \ .$$
I was a bit lazy and I did not compute the powers of $7$.  :)

With this last equation, you'll be able to compute the value of $a$. To obtain the value of $b$ you can use one of the other equations (I suggest using the one with the smaller numbers).

Comment: this helps could you help me a little more?

Comment: just with the equations

Comment: still a little confused first time doing this! how do i get the a and b out of this 2 equations? cause a and b are still both in there? i can slove when its one variable but not 2.

Comment: @EnriqueRodriguez: I added another step in the solution. I believe that you can now compute the final result on your own.